# Can't create [web3j] tag because [web3js] tag exists

Tags: support, tags

[web3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3js) is the tag for the JavaScript API for Ethereum.

[web3j](https://docs.web3j.io) is a Java library for interacting with Ethereum. They are distinct.

However, I can't create [web3j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3j) because [web3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3js) exists and the spelling is too similar:

[image]

I've noticed a few questions already mistakenly tagged as [web3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3js) even though they pertain to the Java web3j library and not JavaScript.

Possible examples of incorrectly tagged questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3js+java

Comment: Sound like a bug...? (pluralization of tag or something) Try `web3j-ethereum` or `web3j-java`?

Comment: This is not a bug, but a method to prevent accidental tag creation if you make a typo, creation of plurals of existing tags, creation of ambiguous tags, etc. If it's reasonable to have both a `web3j` tag and a `web3js` tag (it sounds reasonable to me), then a mod can create it. This post is the correct way to get that done.

Comment: I agree it should get a separate tag, but I also agree with @user202729 that it should have a distinct name too, otherwise they can be easily confused, maybe also suggesting a rename of the existing `web3js` as well

Comment: I see someone created the [tag:web3-java] tag in the meantime.

Comment: Voting to close as no repro because [tag:web3-java] exists now for this.